# What are the usability test cases for given scenario?

Tags: manual-testing

I have three fields: username, password and confirm password. Next to those fields there is a submit button.

1. Explain all possible usability test cases I can make out of it.
2. If i got an error even after entering correct values in all fields
   and submit the form, what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Why do you ask? Is this something you have to do or an interview question?

Comment: This question is covered under what not to ask in the FAQ.  

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you are asking is a "classic" one. This question is one of the most frequent asked questions at QA interviews. Maybe this is why quite many articles, blogs are discussing about the possibilities and scenarios, like [this](http://www.portnov.com/forums/showthread.php?522-Write-test-cases-for-Login-Password-functionality), [this](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/quality/browser/front-end/testcases/password-manager/) or [this](http://reddytesting.blogspot.ro/2011/05/reusable-test-cases-for-web-based.html).

I think, for your **first question** you can give yourself the answer by reading those pages. Just a suggestion: there *always* is another test case which can be run.

As for the **second question**, I think, that is the scenario which is named bug or failure. There is a "path" which can be found in any testing documentation: a failure or a bug is the result of an error. An error causes a fault which results a failure. Now, it seems that you found one. So the next step is to **report the problem**: report ID, date, version, name of the tester, environment specification, steps and the result vs expected result.

Comment: I am not sure this relates to usability.